# What to read for an introduction on the epistemology of logic?

Tags: logic, epistemology

I would like to read about the epistemology of logic, preferably at a undergraduate level (not being a philosopher myself). What (text)book should I read for a good introduction on these topics?

The background of my question is that I tend to be quite skeptical about what we can know, but I haven't found ways to poke holes in logic itself. However I do know there exist things like logical pluralism, though I do not know exactly what it means (yet).

Comment: This is not exactly textbook material. [Boghossian's Knowledge of Logic](http://paulboghossian.com/docs/KL.pdf) is a readable overview. There is a relatively accessible [paper of Beall and Restall](http://consequently.org/papers/pluralism.pdf) on logical pluralism, they also have a [book on the subject](https://ndpr.nd.edu/news/logical-pluralism/).

Comment: Off-label suggestion: try reading about logical fallacies. In many cases, the vocabulary used there explains logic very well.

Comment: @barrycarter I know about logic and also about logical fallacies, but my question is about the epistemic validity of logic itself.

Comment: Maybe useful : Carlo Cellucci, [Rethinking Logic : Logic in Relation to Mathematics Evolution and Method](https://books.google.it/books?id=TczHBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2013)

Comment: Also useful : Penelope Rush (editor), [The Metaphysics of Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=GEilBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Cambridge (2014) and Penelope Maddy, [The Logical Must: Wittgenstein on Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=VeToAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Oxford (2014) and Penelope Maddy, [The philosophy of logic](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsl/1352802979), *BSL* (2012).

Comment: @GambitSquared My mistake. I confused the words epistemology and semantics, sigh.